# Using jquery rotate in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, carousel, image-rotation

My problem is that I am getting some images in my fancybox. The images can be clicked at any angle and are to be rotated on [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).
I am using [jQuery Rotator](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) to rotate the images and the code is as below:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.fancybox-wrap', function(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
        $(this).find('.fancybox-skin').rotate(90);
        $(this).find('.fancybox-skin').height($(window).height());
    }
});
```

The code works fine but the problem is that the background and images do not resize according to the canvas. 
How can i achieve it? 
PLease help..!!!

Comment: have you tried calling the `$.fancybox.update()` or `$.fancybox.reposition()` methods after the rotation? note: those methods are for v2.x

Comment: I tried.. but dint work :(... The same version I am using..

Comment: Well its a jQueryRotate not jQuery Rotator ;) Still not much of help I can give here so.. :(